# jQuery ResponsiveSlides - How to start Slider with last picture in <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently using [responsiveSlides](https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js)
as an image slider on our web page. 
It is a jQuery slider using an HTML unsorted list of images to slide through (automatically in my case).

Now the Issue i am having is, that before the slider actually starts (meaning the script is loaded) there is the last picture in the unsorted list displayed, for a short moment. Then the slider starts his work with the first image in that list.

I tried using a minified version of the js-file, and load that script at the very beginning of my HTML markup. This actually shortened the display time of the last picture, but it is still noticeable and annoying. (This happens with every click on a navigation point, as the page is loading new...)

Also i experimented with timeout function (js) to display the unsorted list containing div after some miliseconds, or on document.ready state, etc..

But all of theses attempts where ugly.

So now i am at the point, where i try to understand how the whole slider script is working, and i assume there must be a point, where i can set to start with the last picture in my unsorted list, instead of starting with the first one, but i just can't find that point in the code.

I couldn't manage to post the code here with proper syntax highlighting, so you can find the code [here](https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js/blob/master/responsiveslides.js)

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: I have set index = $slide.length in line 50, which sets the last picture as primary, now i still need to find where the loop is and maybe change it from incrementing to decrementing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see on their demo page, sliding happens because of changing z-index, so slides like a pie.
In you slider you may see the last slide while script is initializing because of already applied CSS, but not JS yet.
I'd suggest to add `opacity: 0;` in CSS to all your slides. When JS will be ready, it'll add `opacity: 1;` itself.

Comment: Thanks Anarion, as suggested, i added `opacity:0` to all but the first slide. Now this thing works like a charm.